# Difference between '%p' and 'my %p'?

Tags: perl, mojo, mojolicious

```
% %p = ('option1' => 'Option 1', 
% 'option2' => 'Option 2', 
% 'option3' => 'Option 3'
% );
    <select name="killer_feature" id="killer_feature" class="select">
% foreach (keys %p) {
% my $selected = param('killer_feature') && param('killer_feature') eq $_ ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
% if (!param('killer_feature') && $_ eq 'option2') { $selected = 'selected="selected"' }
    <option value=" <%=$_%>" <%= $selected %>>
        <%= $p{$_} %>
    </option>
% }
    </select>
```

the above code breaks the app by returning 'Internal server error', but if I smiply edit the very first line to `% my %p` (I tried it because some other controls have this format) it works, I wonder whats the difference between the two.

Its a perl app built on Mojolicious web framework.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Raw `%p` says to use a global (package) variable "%p". To be more technical, by default, a non-declared variable name is considered to be a package variable and is silently pre-pended with the name of the current package - e.g. it would be really referring to `%main::p` variable since you're in the main package by default.

**BUT** If the Perl code is run by the interpreter with the `use strict` pragma enabled (as it is with mojo), this automatic pre-pending of a current package name to un-declared variables does not happen, and therefore the code with such a variable will not compile as the variable `%p` is not actually known from either a lexical scope declaration or package symbol table.

Adding `my` declares the "%p" variable into a local (lexical) scope and it will now happily satisfy the `strict` pragma.

A much more in-depth (and better written) explanation of variable scoping in Perl is avialable from Randal Schwartz's Stonehendge consulting web site: http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/UnixReview/col46.html

Comment: But I wonder why some of the other elements in the same file use `% %p` without error?

Comment: Once it's declared once at the top of the file, its lexical scope will extend to the end of the file.

Comment: Also, the starting "%" is totally unrelated - it's merely a way for mojo to know something is a template's Perl code as opposed to HTML

Answer (score 2):

**It seems like your real question is:** what is the `my` keyword and why is it needed?

`my` is used to declare the variable in the local scope and also locally to a subroutine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

   my $foo = "defined in outer";
   print_result ("outer",$foo);             # outer: defined in outer

   {
      # $foo has not yet been defined locally
      print_result ("inner",$foo);          # inner: defined in outer

      my $foo = "defined in inner";         # defining $foo locally

      print_result ("inner",$foo);          # inner: defined in inner 

      my $foo;                              # re-declaring $foo

      print_result ("inner", $foo);         # inner:  
   } 

   # even though $foo was defined in the subroutine, it did not
   # override the $foo outside the subroutine (localization occured)
   print_result ("outer",$foo);             # main: defined in main      


   sub print_result {
      my ($proc,$value) = @_;
      print qq{$proc:\t$value\n};
   }
```

Because Mojolicious uses the `use strict` it requires all variables to be declared with (`my`, `our`, `local`, etc).

Notice what happens when you use `my` more than once in the code above.  It unnecessarily redeclares the variable, overwriting what was previously assigned.

Like most programming languages, you only need to declare a variable once and then use that variable over again as necessary.